# Ionic React Promise not waiting after setting State on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise, ionic-react

Okay I have the following problem:

On a button click, I want to do a GET-Request to retrieve lat/lon data of a address, update the state of the component and then move on to the next page with the updated state as passed data.

My code looks like this:

```
// useState setup
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
  const [lon, setLon] = useState(0);

// async function which sets the state
  async function geocode (text: string) {
    let request = 'https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?' +
    '&searchtext=' + text +
    '&maxresults=1'+
    '&gen=9'+
    '&apiKey=xxx';

    fetch(request)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("before setting state values:", result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Latitude, result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Longitude);
        setLat(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Latitude);
        setLon(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition[0].Longitude); 
        
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
          console.log("in promise values:", lat,lon);
          setTimeout(resolve, 10);
        })   
 
      })
   }

// btn click function
  async function btnClick (e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (checkInputs()) {
      await geocode(address);
      console.log("after promise values",lat,lon);
      history.push({
        pathname: '/page/ResultMap',
          state: {
              address: address,
              transportTime: transportTime,
              transportType: transportType,
              lat: lat,
              lon: lon                  
            }
          }
      )}
  }
```

And the console logs me this:

```
after promise values 0 0 
before setting state values: 52.51605 13.37691 
in promise values: 0 0
```

I would honestly expect that history.push() waits until the await geocode(address) resolves to continue the method execution.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using regular Promises, and not async/await.